# What is more common: harbour or port?

Tags: word-usage

What is more common to say: The ship arrives in the harbour or port of Lisbon?

Comment: They're different things.

Comment: *Port can be understood as a place, where loading and unloading of ships and boats are done. The term port is often juxtaposed with harbour, which implies a place along a coast where ships or boats can take shelter if the atmospheric conditions are not well for sailing.*
https://keydifferences.com/difference-between-port-and-harbour.html

Comment: Curiously, although by "strict" definitions you'd think that ***ports*** must be smaller than ***harbours*** (since a port is often situated *within* something that could be defined as a harbour), the most immediate distinction that comes to mind for me is ***ports are big, harbours are small***. Presumably because there are plenty of very small out-of-the-way harbours, but to be an actual ***port*** implies substantial infrastructure.

Comment: There are many differences in the sense in which each word is used, but one of them is that "port" would always suggest an urban place, with connections to other forms of  transport such as road and/or rail. A "harbour" could exist quite naturally on a desert island.  Having said that it is almost essential for a port also to have a harbour - unless it is an airport of course.

Comment: @FumbleFingers -- well, most ports are within harbors — nobody wants their ship sunk while they are trying to unload it — but a port is only smaller than the particular harbor that contains it.  A harbor can be arbitrarily small.  If it's big enough to float a dinghy, it could be a harbor.  A port necessarily has all sorts of amenities: docks, roads and/or rail connections, vendors (like chandleries and tugboats).  Any port is naturally going to be fairly large, and therefore must be located in a fairly large harbor.

Comment: @FumbleFingers A port is not, necessarily, within a harbour. A harbour is defined by [the Oxford Living Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/harbour) as **A place on the coast where ships may moor in shelter**. Many ports are (or used to be) well inland on rivers, examples that spring to mind are Cairo in Illinois; London, Hull and Goole in England; Koko in  Nigeria; Bonthe in Sierra Leone and so on. Some of these are quite close to river moths but others, particularly Cairo, are a very long way from the sea but still deal (or dealt) with big vessels and lots of cargo.

Comment: @BoldBen: I know that, which is why I said  *a port is **often** situated within ... a harbour.* It was Malvolio who said above that *Any port ... **must** be located in a fairly large harbor*. (You can tell us apart by how we spell "harbo[u]r"! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oops, sorry!

Comment: @FumbleFingers -- sorry, to be specific, if a seaport is inside a harbor (instead of some other form of shelter like a river), then the harbor has to be large — large enough to contain the port.

Answer (score 3):

The words have different meanings.

A *harbor* refers to an area of water that is protected (by natural or manmade breakwaters) from the open ocean.

A *port* is a place where large vehicles load and offload and where people enter a country.

So the ship enters the harbor of Lisbon when it sails into the calm water; it enters the port when it actually docks.

Comment: @FumbleFingers is surely right and there must be something wrong with the apparently clear logic here. Just up the Portuguese coast is the city of Porto:  the important thing about that city is that it is a port not that it has docks.

Comment: That's correct—a harbor is a body of water (often supporting a port), while a port is a manmade facility or group of facilities (often located on or around, or including, a harbor). So, as for which is more common in the given example of Lisbon, it would depend on what the more common usage is locally. Is there a body of water commonly known as Lisbon Harbor, or similar, as there is in, say, Boston? Or is it more akin to Los Angeles, where there term "Port of LA" is frequently encountered?